# Edge and Windows Authentication

Tags: authentication, asp.net-core, microsoft-edge

I created an out-of-the-box ASP.NET 5 application with Windows Authentication as a test. If I hit F5 and launch it in Edge, I get presented with a login prompt. If I browse to an application on an internal web server that requires Windows Authentication, it works fine.

Is there something specific I need to do in order to be able to debug web application with Windows Authentication from localhost?

**EDIT:** The same application works fine in IE11 and other browsers. This is Edge 25.10586.0.0.